# Removal of SQLite database file using Java doesn't work

Tags: java, sqlite

These code blocks work but...
If I use this blocks one by one my application doesn't remove database file. (`result` is equeal to `false`)

sqlite manage part:

```
    // sqlite manage

        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC").newInstance();            
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/"+ myDBpath);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
    //some calculations
    stmt.close();
```

removal part:

```
    //remove this file
    boolean result = new File(myDBpath).delete();
```

But if I use only remove code without database operations it works! Why? How can I avoid it?

Comment: You also need to close the connection:  `conn.close();`

Comment: @Andie2302, you are right. already found by the answer below. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you are using the database connection then your sql file is in use and hence you cannot delete it.

And when you don't use the database operation then the sql file is not in use and hence it can be deleted easily. So delete the file you need to make sure that there is no open connection with your database and once all the connections are closed you can delete the file.
change

```
stmt.close();
```

into

```
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```

Comment: How can I remove this connection?

Comment: @Vyacheslav:- As you are doing it. You have to close the connection and then delete the file.